# Use of dlookr package and diagnosed_paged_report funcion in R to generate a pdf report

Tags: r, report, data-quality

I tried to generate a dataframe diagnose pdf report using the `diagnose_paged_report()` function from the `dloohkr` package, but I am getting this error message:

> Output created: diagnosis_paged_temp.html
> Warning: A runtime exception has occured while executing JavaScript
> Runtime exception message:
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
> at findPage (http://127.0.0.1:7685/diagnosis_paged_temp.html:90:15)
> at tocEntriesInfos (http://127.0.0.1:7685/diagnosis_paged_temp.html:120:20)
> at window.PagedConfig.after (http://127.0.0.1:7685/diagnosis_paged_temp.html:150:24)
> at http://127.0.0.1:7685/diagnosis_paged_temp.html:31271:17
> Error in force(expr) : Failed to generate output in 30 seconds (timeout).

I've tried to update packages and remove empty strings present in the dataframe. The code is:

```
diagnose_paged_report(rmae, output_format = c("pdf"), output_file = "diagnostico rmae", output_dir = "C:/Users/josec/Documents/")
```